# Rewrite default language URL

Tags: redirect, typo3, http-status-code-301

I just have setup a typo3 website. Page is running well. But got some error. My Onpage optimization everytime gives me a bad feedback because of the default language tag.

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact/
```

and

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact/?L=0
```

When I try to redirect it well, with a permanent moved 301 redirect, it creates a loop and I can´t redirect his well.

I tried to redirect it with my_redirects extension  and also with htacess, but I got just a bad result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks @JoeC. I will check this Checklist. Sorry for my "too fast"-Post.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say your default language is `en` and your secondary language is `es` then try this snippet in your `<typo3root>/typoconf/realurl_conf.php`.

```
    'preVars' => array (
        0 => array (
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array (
                'es' => '1',
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
    ),
```

I think your missing the `'noMatch' => 'bypass',` it allows the L parameter to be absent.

This will result in:

- English / default URL: `www.mywebsite.com/contact/`
- Spanish URL: `www.mywebsite.com/es/contacto/`